# How to activate jquery features inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jscrollpane

I have an iframe with multiple jquery features inside of it, and I cannot figure out how to call any of the functions properly to where the jquery works. When I access the iframe page directly, the jquery works perfectly, but when I access the frame's parent, the jquery doesn't activate. I've looked around at other answers for this and simply have not been able to figure it out.

For example, inside the iframe I have a couple divs with a jScrollpane on them. Typically, to activate jScrollpane, I have to have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function()
{
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
</script>
```

But I can't figure out how to call this function from the parent page at all. I don't really know jquery, so if someone could literally spell out how I can get this function activated within the iframe, I would be so grateful!

Comment: @NeelBasu that would be hard since it is an iFrame

Comment: Yeah I honestly wouldn't know how to put this particular scenario on jsfiddle, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a function in the iframe using jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){    
  $("#id_of_your_frame").load(function(){
   $("#id_of_your_frame").contents().find(".scroll-pane").jScrollPane();
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I'm assuming this goes on the parent page right? Does it need to be accompanied with anything else or just put in the <head> area as is? I did try it, didn't work unfortunately.

As far as the actual function, should that go in the head of the parent page as well or is that supposed to be in the iframe?

Comment: I corrected my answer. You can paste this code into the <head> area or other place of the parent page. It should work if a source of the iframe is on the same site the parent page on.